# Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack, migrated from Angular 4 to 6

Tags: angular

I had Angular 4 project so i've updated it to Angular 6. I used this guide: https://dev.to/chiangs/upgrading-to-angular-6-309p
Unfortunelly there's a problem I can't handle.

```
\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:73
            throw new Error('Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack.');
            ^

Error: Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:73:19)
    at new AngularCompilerPlugin (\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:45:14)

    at Object.<anonymous> (\frontend\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:234:54)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! charls@0.0.1 webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js" "--open" "--progress" "--profile" "--watch" "--content-base" "src/"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

I've read that's propably problem with @ngtools but unfortunettly I can't see a solution.

https://github.com/angular/ngtools-webpack-builds - that's not working for me(or it's just my luck of knowledge, I've started learning angular week ago :D).

Thanks in advance!